# I have some questions about the sentence

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

**The focal point of the magazine's efforts in this respect came with the rise of Marcus Garvey, the gifted Jamaican leader whose "Back-to-Africa" movement, as it was popularly called, was founded on the premise, according to Du Bois, that " a black skin was in itself a sort of patent to nobility".**

I thought that the main sentence of this sentence is "the focal point came with the rise". But one video I saw told me that the verb of the main sentence was "was founded". What exactly is the main sentence here? Could you please answer me?
Here comes another question. What exactly does the phrase "according to Du Bois" describe? In my opinion, it describes probably the opinion that "Back-to-Africa" was founded on the premise that blabla..., however, the google translator tells me that it describes the opinion that the focal point came with the rise of .....(the whole sentence).

I'm so sorry for my poor expression. Could anybody help me? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main verb in the sentence is "came" ("...this respect *came* with the rise ...") all the other verbs are in subsidiary clauses.

I don't really understand the second part of your question.  The phrase with "according to Du Bois" means that it was [Du Bois](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W._E._B._Du_Bois)'s opinion that Garvey's *"Back-to-Africa" Movement ... was founded on the premise* that *"a black skin was in itself a sort of patent to nobility"*.

Comment: Exactly, what I means is that the Google translator tells me that "according to Du Bois" means that it was Du Bois's opinion that The focal point of the magazine's efforts in this respect...nobility, which makes me feel so confused. But now thank you for your answer, it really helps me.